# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.isar.myplatform/com.isar.myplatform.MainActivity}

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, google-play

**I am trying to upload your application, which I programmed in the Flutter language, to Google Play, but I am facing the following problem in the stability section:**

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.isar.myplatform/com.isar.myplatform.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-zS75G07QWY7mYvwg-pIH_A==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.x86.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-zS75G07QWY7mYvwg-pIH_A==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-zS75G07QWY7mYvwg-pIH_A==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.x86.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2913)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3048)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1808)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6669)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-zS75G07QWY7mYvwg-pIH_A==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.x86.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-zS75G07QWY7mYvwg-pIH_A==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-zS75G07QWY7mYvwg-pIH_A==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.x86.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.ensureInitializationComplete (FlutterLoader.java)
  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineGroup.<init> (FlutterEngineGroup.java)
  at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.setupFlutterEngine (FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java)
  at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onAttach (FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java)
  at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate (FlutterActivity.java)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7136)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7127)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1271)
  at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (MonitoringInstrumentation.java:2)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2893)
Caused by java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-zS75G07QWY7mYvwg-pIH_A==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.x86.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-zS75G07QWY7mYvwg-pIH_A==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-zS75G07QWY7mYvwg-pIH_A==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.x86.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report (FutureTask.java:123)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get (FutureTask.java:193)
  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.ensureInitializationComplete (FlutterLoader.java)
Caused by java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-zS75G07QWY7mYvwg-pIH_A==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.x86.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-zS75G07QWY7mYvwg-pIH_A==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-zS75G07QWY7mYvwg-pIH_A==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.x86.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.isar.myplatform--gn7KSXTGpo9W8_VC2LdyQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0 (Runtime.java:1012)
  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary (System.java:1669)
  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary (FlutterJNI.java)
  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call (FlutterLoader.java)
  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call (FlutterLoader.java)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```

[image: my androidMainfest]

Comment: Are you able to compile and build the application locally?

Comment: yes sure I'm able to compile